# How Do the KeyEvent.VK_REDO and Similar Constants Work in an Accelerator?

Tags: java, keyevent, undo-redo, accelerator

I'm trying to create menu item accelerators for undo, redo, etc. in a Java application so I can access them with key commands. I also want to make it so that the proper key command appears on the proper platform. For some menu items, like "Undo", it's pretty simple because it's <kbd>Cmd</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>:

```
this.undoMenuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
                    KeyEvent.VK_Z, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask()));
```

The method `getMenuShortcutKeyMask()` returns the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> key on a Mac and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key on a Windows machine. So far so good.

But some menu items have drastically different key combinations on different platforms. To Redo on Mac OS, you do <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, but on Windows you do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>. Thus the above code won't work unless you do an if/then statement to check what platform you are on and pass one of two sets of parameters into the function.

I noticed that in the [KeyEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) class are constants such as [`KeyEvent.REDO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_REDO). I'm presuming that this is a constant for the "Redo" key combination, although I'm not sure because there isn't any documentation about what it does. So I tried the following:

```
this.redoMenuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
                    KeyEvent.VK_REDO, 0));
```

I had hoped that this would result in the appropriate key combination applied as an accelerator, but instead no accelerator appears to be assigned (i.e. there isn't any indicator of the key combination next of the name of the menu item). Is this the proper use of `KeyEvent.VK_UNDO` and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure either, but I'm suspecting it is related to a special undo/redo key in some keyboards

Comment: The int value for VK_UNDO is 65483. Which should be same on all the machines i think. because it has been defined as a static constant in the JRE itself. so it shouldn't be platform dependent. Be it windows, mac and/or linux.